# What is the output of the query if the query try to fetch information form same table multiple time

Tags: sql

Consider the following relational data table, employee. Now find the output for the following SQL statement?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM employee, employee, employee
```

`Employee` table

| gid | name | Three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E101 | John | HRM |
| E102 | Lucy | Marketing |
| E103 | Rick | Management |

Comment: Run it and find out.

Answer (score 1):

This will produce error since you didn't use unique aliases.  You need to assign unique name (alias) to all the tables in from clause. But you should run it first. Here I am sharing a fiddle link please go there and run the query.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table employee (gid varchar(20), name    varchar(20),Three varchar(20));
insert into employee values('E101','John','HRM');
insert into employee values('E102','Lucy','Marketing');
insert into employee values('E103','Rick','Management');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT count(*) From employee a, employee b, employee c;
```

| count(*) |
| --- |
| 27 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: @rayhanrjt if this answer helped you Please accept it as answer by clicking the green check.